# General solution for material derivative equal to zero

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I have a known scalar valued-velocity function $u$ which only depends on time; that is, $u = u(t)$. I want to solve the PDE
$$ 
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + u\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = 0,
$$
where $\rho = \rho(x, t)$ is the density of the fluid under study. In other words, I want to solve
$$
\frac{D\rho}{Dt} = 0,
$$
where $D/Dt$ denotes the material derivative. Does a general closed-form solution exist? I know in the case of $u = $ constant it does, but I can't find anything about the varying coefficient case. I would guess not, but it would be nice to verify this before I go down the numerical route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us consider the initial-value problem $\rho(x,0) = \rho_0(x)$. The [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) consists in introducing the parameterization $\rho(x(t),t)$ of the density. Differentiation w.r.t. time gives
$$
\frac{\text d }{\text d t}\rho = \rho_x\, \frac{\text d }{\text d t}x + \rho_t \, .
$$
Using the PDE $\rho_t + u \rho_x = 0$, one writes the system of characteristic equations
$$
\frac{\text d }{\text d t}\rho = 0\,  , \qquad 
\frac{\text d }{\text d t}x = u\, .
$$
Letting $\rho(0) = \rho_0(x_0)$ gives $\rho(x(t),t) = \rho_0(x_0)$, and letting $x(0) = x_0$ gives $x(t) = x_0 + \int_{0}^{t}u(s)\,\text d s$.
Combining both equations and going back to the original variables, we have
$$
\rho(x,t) = \rho_0\left(x - \int_{0}^{t}u(s)\,\text d s\right) .
$$
The constant velocity case $u(t) = \bar u$ is included in this formula, which gives $\rho(x,t) = \rho_0(x - \bar u t)$.

Comment: Amazing, thanks @Harry49.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the integral curves of $u$ and set $\rho$ to constant along them (see [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics)).